# visual studio Tableadapter sql command error

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am using report viewer in visual studio to show my report data and i tried to configure the sql query. Unfortunately it show me error message when i tried to build it. Here have a look to my sql command,

```
SELECT `AttID`, `EmployeeID`, `EmployeeName`, `Department`, `loginDate`, `month`, `status`, `lateReason`, `InTime`, `OutTime`,
       `TotalTime`, Count(*) 
As LateFrequency FROM `attendance` 
Group By `EmployeeID` 
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

It show me Error in HAVING Clause, Unable to parse query text. (I tried it at w3school sql and it was work)
Then i modify and changed it to this sql command

```
SELECT `AttID`, `EmployeeID`, `EmployeeName`, `Department`, `loginDate`, `month`, `status`, `lateReason`, `InTime`, `OutTime`, 
       `TotalTime`, 
       Count(CASE WHEN(`month`=@month)AND(`status`=`2`) AS LateFrequency
       FROM `attendance` 
       Group By `EmployeeID`
```

It still show me error message:

> Error in SELECT clause:expression near 'As'. Error in SELECT clause:expression near 'FROM' Missing FROM clause. Unable to parse query text.

May I know what wrong with the sql command.

Comment: Do check the syntax for **case** statement in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error there, use this:

```
SELECT `AttID`, `EmployeeID`, `EmployeeName`, `Department`, `loginDate`, `month`, `status`, `lateReason`, `InTime`, `OutTime`, `TotalTime`, 
       Count(CASE WHEN `month`=@month AND `status`=2 then 1 end) AS LateFrequency
FROM `attendance` 
Group By `EmployeeID`
```

Case expression syntax:

```
CASE WHEN <conditions>
     THEN < >
     ELSE < >(optional)
END
```

You were missing the THEN and the END.